# How could I iterate through list of abstract type, containing non-abstract types derived from that abstract class?

Tags: c#

I need to iterate through list I created, but can't access objects inside. I tried a few different functions but nothing worked and I'm afraid I'm using the wrong tools for the job.

```cs
namespace WholesaleApp
{
 
    internal class Program : Wholesale
    {
        static string filePath = "C:\\Wholesale.txt";
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Merchandise> productList = new List<Merchandise>();

            productList = ReadFromFile(filePath);
            foreach(Merchandise merchandise in productList)
            {
                //this is where I'm trying to access objects inside and display them
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my abstract class:

```cs
namespace WholesaleApp
{
    internal abstract class Merchandise
    {
        public string merchandiseName { get; set; }
        public int merchandiseAmount { get; set; }

        public Merchandise(string name, int amount)
        {
            merchandiseName = name;
            merchandiseAmount = amount;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is one of the three classes deriving from `Merchandise` abstract class:

```cs
namespace WholesaleApp
{
    internal class MerchandiseClothing : Merchandise
    {

        public string clothSize { get; set; }
        public string clothType { get; set; }

        public MerchandiseClothing(string _clothType, string _clothSize, string name, int amount) : base(name, amount)
        {
            clothType = _clothType;
            clothSize = _clothSize;
        }
        
        public void ReturnAll()
        {
            Console.Write(merchandiseName+" of type: "+clothSize+" in amount: "+merchandiseAmount+ " and jeep status is: "+clothType);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my function where I add everything to the final list:

```cs
namespace WholesaleApp
{
    internal class Wholesale 
    {
        static public List<Merchandise> ReadFromFile(string filePath)
        {
        List<Merchandise> result = new List<Merchandise>();

        string line;
        StreamReader reader = null!;
            try
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                
                line = reader.ReadLine()!;
                
                while (line != null)
                {
                    string[] words = line.Split(';');
                    if (words[0] == "MerchandiseComputer")
                    {
                        result.Add(new MerchandiseComputer(words[1], words[2], Int32.Parse(words[3])));
                    }
                    else if (words[0] == "MerchandiseCarParts")
                    {
                        result.Add(new MerchandiseCarParts(bool.Parse(words[1]), words[3], words[2], Int32.Parse(words[4])));
                    }
                    else if (words[0] == "MerchandiseClothing")
                    {
                        result.Add(new MerchandiseClothing(words[1], words[2], words[3], Int32.Parse(words[4])));
                    }

                    line = reader.ReadLine()!;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, don't use try/catch until you know the program works.  It hides too many issues.  Also, you're passing a filename into `ReadFromFile`, but you are ignoring that and hard-coding the file name.  Have you added debug prints into `ReadFromFile` to see what it is you are reading?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for a hint with try/catch, i will prevent from using it before i test everything! The hard-code there is just a slip, i was fixing an error earlier and left it, i will correct that in the post in just a second. I added those debug prints, and even checked if the list is populated by the objects by calling few methods in main, and everything seems like they are in the list, and the type is fine, but i can't access them.

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "can't access objects inside?" Can you please be specific?

Comment: @JohnWu Of course, sorry for being too vague. By saying i can't access the objects inside the list i mean that i cannot use any method or take any action (that i know about of course:)) to call a method, for example returnAll() on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to iterate here iterate through objects already. If you want to use specific fields from each specific class, you can put here a check on type and do whatever you want. For example:

```
foreach (Merchandise merchandise in productList)
{
    if (merchandise is MerchandiseClothing clothing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(clothing.clothSize); //Can be use any field from Clothing class 
        Console.WriteLine(clothing.merchandiseAmount); //And also from parent
    }
    else if (merchandise is MerchandiseComputer computer)
    {
        //Do what you want
    }
}
```

However, better to make abstract method like `WriteToConsole` in `Merchandise` class and override it in each implementation. Like `ReturnAll` method in your `MerchandiseClothing` class

Comment: That's awesome, exactly what i tried to achieve! Idea about doing abstract method WriteToConsole() and overriding it is better though, like you said. I have one more question, could you say where should i look to learn and understand what you did in line 3? I just don't get why can we add "clothing" to the if statement, and why it works:)

Comment: Sure, it is a new C# feature named Pattern Matching https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching

Comment: I know i shouldn't but i can't help myself, big thanks once again, you are great help:)!